# Separating two scripts for "scroll to div"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to do this myself but I guess I'm not skilled enough, I quit trying and came to ask for help.
I got this script for my menu on a one page website.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        //MENU
        $('.menu ul li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('id', '');
            })
            $(this).attr('id', 'active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
            }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });            
    });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('.menu ul li a').attr("id", "");
                currentLink.attr("id", "active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.attr("id", "");
            }
        });
    }
```

And it works perfectly as I want BUT I also have links throughout my website that I want them to do the same.

I did that myself but the 2 scripts were coliding with each other, it was applying the `class active` to the link as well. When I tried to reverse the situation, it was working but it wasn't applying the `class active` on the menu...

I was really confused and I also am not that much of a js/jquery programmer.

Could anyone have a suggestion for how to separate the scripts? For example here: `<a href="#contactos" class="solicitar_visita"><span>SOLICITE A NOSSA VISITA</span></a>`. This sends the user to the `div contactos` but it doesn't animate and I want it to do so.

Any ideas?

EDIT: for this second script I don't want to apply any `active class`. Just slide to the desired `div`.

EDIT 2: I believe I wasn't clear. I want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

            //MENU
            $('.menu ul li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document).off("scroll");

                $('a').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('id', '');
                })
                $(this).attr('id', 'active');

                var target = this.hash;
                $target = $(target);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
                }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
                });
            });

            //OTHER LINKS
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document).off("scroll");

                var target = this.hash;
                $target = $(target);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
                }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
                });
            });            
        });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('.menu ul li a').attr("id", "");
                currentLink.attr("id", "active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.attr("id", "");
            }
        });
    }
```

BUT the "OTHER LINKS" script will interfere with the menu script. I don't know if I'm doing things right, what I know is that the way I do, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addClass** and **removeClass** instead of attr.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        //MENU
        $('.menu ul li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
            }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });            
    });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('.menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```